# The formula expression is invalid: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 9

Tags: validation-rule

```
IF(
  AND(
    ISPICKVAL([Bug__c].Bug_Classification__c,'Enhancement'),
    [Bug__c].RecordType.Name ='PDK Bug'
  ),'a8I0l0000008QozEAE',
  AND(
    ISPICKVAL([Bug__c].Bug_Classification__c,'Internal Bug'),
    [Bug__c].RecordType.Name ='PDK Bug'
  ),'a8I0l0000008QrPEAU',
  AND(
    ISPICKVAL([Bug__c].Bug_Classification__c,'Product Bug'),
    [Bug__c].RecordType.Name ='PDK Bug'
  ),'a8I0l0000008QrUEAU',
  AND(
    ISPICKVAL([Bug__c].Bug_Classification__c,'Questions'),
    [Bug__c].RecordType.Name ='PDK Bug'
  ),'a8I0l0000008QrZEAU',"")
```

Comment: Put the business rule what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use "nested if statements".

```
IF(
  AND(
    ISPICKVAL([Bug__c].Bug_Classification__c,'Enhancement'),
    [Bug__c].RecordType.Name ='PDK Bug'
  ),'a8I0l0000008QozEAE',
  IF(AND(
    ISPICKVAL([Bug__c].Bug_Classification__c,'Internal Bug'),
    [Bug__c].RecordType.Name ='PDK Bug'
  ),'a8I0l0000008QrPEAU',
  IF(AND(
    ISPICKVAL([Bug__c].Bug_Classification__c,'Product Bug'),
    [Bug__c].RecordType.Name ='PDK Bug'
  ),'a8I0l0000008QrUEAU',
  IF(AND(
    ISPICKVAL([Bug__c].Bug_Classification__c,'Questions'),
    [Bug__c].RecordType.Name ='PDK Bug'
  ),'a8I0l0000008QrZEAU',""))))
```

Each IF statement must have three parameters:

```
IF(BooleanValue, ValueWhenTrue, ValueWhenFalse)
```

By the way, you could make this a lot less "ugly" by shuffling some code around:

```
IF(
  [Bug__c].RecordType.Name ='PDK Bug',
  CASE([Bug__c].Bug_Classification__c,
    'Enhancement', 'a8I0l0000008QozEAE',
    'Internal Bug', 'a8I0l0000008QrPEAU',
    'Product Bug', 'a8I0l0000008QrUEAU',
    'Questions', 'a8I0l0000008QrZEAU',
    "")
  "")
```

Comment: Are the square brackets surrounding `Bug__c` really valid syntax?

Comment: @DerekF It is for Process Builder and Flow formulas.

Comment: @DerekF I suspect the OP is mis-tagged as [tag:validation-rule], since it doesn't return a true/false value.